# How to use a .mtl file in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders

I want to use a .mtl file to draw my objects in unity.
Can I somehow convert a .mtl file into a normal Unity material?

My .mtl file is like this:

```
newmtl phongE1SG
illum 4
Kd 0.00 1.00 0.00
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
Ks 0.50 0.50 0.50
```

Is this the same as a Unity material which has the sliders "albedo", "metallic", "smoothness", etc?

Or is there any shader to do it?

Comment: No, this isn't the same as Unity's standard material. Unity now uses a physically-based rendering ([tag:pbr]) system — you can tell by the way it uses metallic and smoothness parameters instead of the older style of specular exponent and sharpness values that the .mtl format uses. Do you want a result that roughly matches your original material and looks good/realistic in Unity's PBR lighting system, or one that faithfully recreates the older phong-style shading your material file describes?

Comment: Allright , im sorry i didnt really know that.
Yes, i would like to recreate the original Material which would look roughlike like what stands in those parameters.

Comment: @DMGregory Should I delete this Question now? Or should I change the question? Is there even a "roughly" answer to this question?

Comment: Sure there's an answer. It's not a super satisfying one ("copy the material colour values then play with the sliders until it looks right"), but I think with a few tips about how to do this / what to look for, it could be a worthwhile answer. I just don't have time to write it just this moment. Maybe someone else will beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `.mtl` file directly to create a material and apply a texture, used in unity. (Yet I have only tested it on `.obj` files).

For example: Just create `Cube.obj` or take any `.obj` file.
Edit the .obj file in any `TextEditor` and get the `Material name` used in the object,.

Then create a `.mtl` file and assign whatever value you want,
like `color`, `texture map`, etc.

If you still don't understand it, comment here. I will make a video to help you understand.

Comment: I have tried this but it still doesnt work- a video would be great. thankyou